# A function isn't re-running in a loop, but I'm getting no errors?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm building a QoL auto-combat program for D&D in Python, using JSON files in Python 3.7.

When I get to the function in my code that determines damage dealt, however, a variable that is equal to a function which returns a boolean does not redefine inside of a loop.

However, I'm also not getting any errors. Is there any way to fix my problem/find out what's wrong?

I'm completely unable to find any answers to this question, whether it was on Quora, Stack Overflow, or any assortment of Python-oriented documentation.

```
for i in range(weapon_hits)
    attack_result = attack_start(enemy_name, stre, throwing)
        for i in range(weapon_hits):
            attack_result = attack_start(enemy_name, stre, throwing)
            if attack_result is True:
                for j in range(weapon_hits):
                    attack_damage = dice(1, weapon_damage)
                    final_damage = final_damage - attack_damage
                    print("The enemy's health is " + str(final_damage))
```

My expected result would be the code to print out, for example,

"The enemy health is 13 (hit)"

"The enemy health is 13 (miss)"

"The enemy health is 6 (hit)"

However, it will only return either all hits, or all misses, rather than a combination. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the actual output currently?

Comment: You have two loops using `i` as the loop variable, both using the same range. Not sure how you think that would work. (They both also use the same values in `attack_start()` as well. Do you have a copy/paste error there?

Comment: @kenwhite I use `i` as the first, `j` as the second

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Actual output from a run I just did 


`The enemy's health is 15


The enemy's health is 15`

Comment: No, you use `i` in the first and second, `j` in the third. Look at the code you posted.

Comment: @KenWhite I actually didn't notice that. I've changed my code since this posting and removed that loop so it doesn't affect my code now but that was part of the problem, thank you for the help.